# Turning/unloading off jquery?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on themeing a single site of a multi-site Drupal install.  The organization that set up the site has jquery 1.2.6 installed which is fine for most things... but as I'm planning on using a few other javascript libraries and maybe a few $.ajax calls, I was hoping for a more up to date jquery for the sake of compatibility.

Is there a way I can write a javascript call to remove the:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery.js?K"></script>
```

and then call my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you thought my friend, You can simply add your new jQuery version, add it after the older version, the older version and it's plugins will be overridden.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery.js?K"></script> 
...
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/jquery-BRAND-NEW-jQuery.js"></script>
```

Comment: -1: This must be the worst possible way to approach the problem.

Comment: @tereško, waiting to see yours. :(

Comment: Best way, if possible, is to remove the older version of jQuery completely and then add the newer version. I'm not familiar with Drupal so maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy, And by removing you mean...? How? of course if he can remove the older version it's the best and the obvious way, I believe it's not so simple or else he wouldn't be asking...

Comment: You assume that it isn't that simple.. has anyone checked though?

Comment: removing the older version means asking.  then begging.  Then waiting while a very slow moving organization decides if a change would affect anything negatively and what impact the change would have on all the other existing sites.  Then getting put on the queue while they get to it.

I've tried doing this with them before on something a lot more minor. It took two months for them to say "Sorry, we can't do it"

Comment: By the way I think, on rereading the question, that what he is trying to do is to get several versions of jQuery loaded in the page at the same time, and the current plugins reference the old versions whereas any new plugins reference the newer version. In which case your answer is half correct, but you would need to save the older version as, say, `$2`, and then change all the older plugins to reference `$2` instead of `$`.

Comment: @LarsTownsend, ok now I understand - as I say, I am not familiar with Drupal. Ok so do as above - reference the new version of jQuery as close as possible, but after, the old version of jQuery. +1 as the answer is correct.

Comment: @tereško, still waiting... if it's the worst, there must be plenty better, where are them?

Comment: Apparently there is actually a jQuery update module in Drupal - check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329261/how-can-you-implement-jquery-code-in-drupal-pages-for-non-coders?rq=1). Not sure if this would be an option..?

Comment: Surely if the old version cannot simply be removed then your answer is not possible either?  If it is then please explain how this is so?

Comment: @JonTaylor, The old jQuery can be in a master page which he can't remove or change, the new jQuery can be added with a javascript code adding the new `<script>` tag. many options.

Comment: Alas, I don't have access to about 90% of the site, only one minor folder with CSS, some scripting, and minimal php.  I can't add modules or touch anything outside of that one sub-directory.

Comment: Bumping a newer jQuery version will likely break existing scripts, expecting $ to be the jQuery object of the old version. The best way is to treat the old jQuery as an other library and load the newer one in noConflict mode.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just push a newer version jQuery by adding/replacing the  tag. Drupal and some modules bundles their own JavaScript that rely on that specific version of jQuery, updating jQuery may break these JavaScript. Most of these script require the jQuery object (from jQuery 1.2.6) to be binded to `$`.

If really needed, you can [load an newer version of jQuery in noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), treating the old jQuery as a an *[other library](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)*. So `$` will still be the old jQuery object for the existing script. Andyou can use newer jQuery version using `jQuery` in your script. Properly written plugins and libraries should access the jQuery object using `jQuery` instead of `$` and so should be loadable (after calling the noConflict() method). IF not, you may need to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [JQuery Update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update). That will take Drupal 6 to JQuery 1.3.2. It also will show you which Drupal core JS files need modified to work with newer versions of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, upon further research, I found an answer here:

http://drupal.org/node/1058168

I used the last solution, unset the old jquery from the $script array and put in 1.8.3 which seems to work so far.